# creating pl/sql tool using dll (c++ codes and DEV c++ compiler)

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, plsql, dev-c++

I am dealing with a `dll` project for my internship. I have to write a C++ code including some basic functions for `pl/sql` with dev c compiler and it must be work as a `pl/sql` tool.I wrote this codes.And i save the source file as `dll` file.I copied the `dll` extension file to plugin directory of `pl/sql` developer.It did not work.
Thank you all.
Here is my header and source code.

```
// header file plsqlHx.h
#ifndef _DLL_H_ 
#define _DLL_H_ 
#define DLL_EX 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) DLL_EX const char* IdentifyPlugIn(int);
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) DLL_EX const char* CreateMenuItem(int);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  DLL_EX void  OnMenuClick(int);

#endif
```

---

```
#include "plsqlHx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

const char *const Desc = "C++Builder Plug-In demo 1"; 
int PlugInID;

const char* IdentifyPlugIn(int ID){
  PlugInID = ID;
  return Desc;
}

const char* CreateMenuItem(int Index){
  switch (Index)
  {
  case 1 : return "Tools / &Plug-In 1 Demo...";
  }
  return "";
}

void OnMenuClick (int Index){
  switch(Index){
  case 11:
    cout << "Hello";
    break;
  case 12: 
    cout << "Goodbye";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You changed the source file extension *.cpp to *.dll ?

Comment: Sounds like you are creating a plugin for [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) (the desktop IDE), not for [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) (the in-database programming language).

Comment: Yes i changed. And yes it is for PL/SQL Developer.